# Multiple awaits in function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm struggling a bit with JS promises.

I am using a library to pull data from Spotify that returns promises.
In my main function I can use an await to build an object from the response data and push it to an array (called nodes):

```js
var nodes = [];

main();


async function main() {

    var id = '0gusqTJKxtU1UTmNRMHZcv';
    var artist = await getArtistFromSpotify(id).then(data => buildArtistObject(data));
    nodes.push(artist);
```

When I debug here then all is good, nodes has my object.

However, when I introduce a 2nd await underneath to make another call:

```js
nodes.forEach((node, i) => {

            if (node.done == false) {
                console.log(node.toString());
                var related_artists =  await getRelatedArtists(node.spotify_id);
```

I get the following error: **SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function**

I thought the first await statement would be resolved and the execution would continue until the next..?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
The other functions, if that helps, are just as follows:

```js
function getArtistFromSpotify(id) {

    let response = spotify
        .request('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/' + id).then(function (data) {
            return data;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error('Error occurred: ' + err);
            return null;
        });

    return response;
}

function getRelatedArtists(id) {
    let response = spotify
        .request('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/' + id + '/related-artists').then(function (data) {
            return data;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error('Error occurred: ' + err);
            return null;
        });

    return response;
}

function buildArtistObject(data) {
    var artist = {
        node_id: nodes.length,
        name: null,
        genres: null,
        popularity: null,
        spotify_id: null,
        done: false
    }

    artist.name = data.name;
    artist.genres = data.genres;
    artist.popularity = data.popularity > 0 ? data.popularity : 0;
    artist.spotify_id = data.id;

    return artist;
}
```

Comment: you should include your entire `main` function and the entire `nodes.forEach(...)` block. it would also be helpful if you include a well-defined input and output.

Comment: As the error message states: `await` keyword can only be used inside an `async` function. In your case, callback function of  `forEach` is not `async`. Another thing is to not mix promise-chaining with `async-await` syntax. Also, consider using `for of` loop, instead of `forEach` to make the async calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below has multiple problems.

```
var nodes = [];    
main();
   
async function main() {
    var id = '0gusqTJKxtU1UTmNRMHZcv';
    var artist = await getArtistFromSpotify(id).then(data => buildArtistObject(data));
    nodes.push(artist);
// ...
```

First of all, `main` mutates global scope `nodes`. Not only is this an antipattern even in synchronous code (functions should not rely on, or modify, global variable names; use parameters and return values instead), in asynchronous code, `nodes` will never be available for use anywhere but within `main`. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Secondly, try to avoid combining `then` and `await`. It's confusing.

It's also a little odd that an array of `nodes` is used, yet only one `artist` is pushed onto it...

As for this code:

```
nodes.forEach((node, i) => {
    if (node.done == false) {
        console.log(node.toString());
        var related_artists =  await getRelatedArtists(node.spotify_id);

// ...
```

The error is self-explanatory. You must add `async` to the enclosing function if you want it to be asynchronous: `nodes.forEach(async (node, i) => { // ...`. But that spawns a new promise chain per node, meaning future code that's dependent on the result won't be able to await all of the promises in the loop resolving. See [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop). The likely solution is `for..of` or [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

While I'm not 100% sure what your final goal is, this is the general pattern I'd use:

```
async function main() {
  const id = '0gusqTJKxtU1UTmNRMHZcv';
  const data = await getArtistFromSpotify(id);
  const artist = await buildArtistObject(data);
  const nodes = [artist]; // odd but I assume you have more artists somewhere...
 
  for (const node of nodes) {
    if (!node.done) {
      const relatedArtists = await getRelatedArtists(node.spotify_id);
    }
  }
  /* or run all promises in parallel: 
  const allRelatedArtists = await Promise.all(
    nodes.filter(e => !e.done).map(e => getRelatedArtists(e.spotify_id))
  );
  */

  // ...
}

main();
```

Since your code isn't runnable and some of the intent is unclear from the context, you'll likely need to adapt this a bit, so consider it pseudocode.

Comment: This has answered my question, thank you. I wasn't realising that the related_artists function wasn't main, but indeed the forEach. Changing it to a for(const x of y) works. I'll tidy up the code too (first time using async).
And yeah, nodes will be getting more artists. I'm building it up for a d3 graph. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You have some misunderstandings of how to use promises -

```js
let response = spotify
  .request(url)
  .then(function(data) { return data })       // this does nothing
  .catch(function (err) {                     // don't swallow errors
    console.error('Error occurred: ' + err);
    return null;
  })

return response
```

You'll be happy there's a more concise way to write your basic functions -

```js
const getArtist = id =>
  spotify
    .request('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/' + id)

const getRelatedArtists = id =>
  spotify
    .request('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/' + id + '/related-artists')
```

Now in your `main` function, we can `await` as many things as needed. Let's first see how we would work with a single artist ID -

```js
async function main(artistId) {
  const artistData = await getArtist(artistId)
  const relatedData = await getRelatedArtists(artistId)
  return buildArtist(artistData, relatedData)
}
```

If you have many artist IDs -

```js
async function main(artistIds) {
  const result = []
  for (const id of artistIds) {
    const artistData = await getArtist(artistId)
    const relatedData = await getRelatedArtists(artistId)
    result.push(buildArtist(artistData, relatedData))
  }
  return result
}
```

Either way, the caller can handle errors as

```js
main([693, 2525, 4598])
  .then(console.log)     // display result
  .catch(console.error)  // handle errors
```

Which is the same as -

```js
main([693, 2525, 4598]).then(console.log, console.error)
```

The pattern above is typical but sub-optimal as the caller has to wait for *all* data to fetch before the complete result is returned. Perhaps you would like to display the information, one-by-one as they are fetched. This is possible with [async generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) -

```js
async function* buildArtists(artistIds) {
  for (const id of artistIds) {
    const artistData = await getArtist(artistId)
    const relatedData = await getRelatedArtists(artistId)
    yield buildArtist(artistData, relatedData)            // <- yield
  }
}

async function main(artistIds) {
  for await (const a of buildArtists(artistIds))    // <- for await
    displayArtist(a)
}

main([693, 2525, 4598]).catch(console.error)
```